# How to add an object to ArrayList

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I am creating a UI with object oriented programming.

In the UI I am trying to add a new team. When I add this team, I want the object of the team to be stored into an ArrayList named 'TeamList'.

I am able to store the team just fine as an object from the UI, but I cannot add the team into the TeamList ArrayList, and im not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I am new to programming so I apologise for any bad errors.

This is my TeamList class ('Team' is an object I've already created):

```
public class TeamList {
    private ArrayList<Team> teamList;

    public TeamList(){
        setTeamList(teamList);
    }

    public ArrayList<Team> getTeamList() {
        return teamList;
    }

    public void setTeamList(ArrayList<Team> teamList) {
        this.teamList = teamList;
    }
```

And this is where Im trying to add 'Team' to 'TeamList':

```
@FXML private void AddingTeam() {
        Team team = new Team(newTeamTextfield.getText());
        team.getTeamName();
     

        TeamList teams = new TeamList();
        teams.add(team);
    }
```

The error is with:

```
teams.add(team);
```

Comment: `TeamList` does not have an `add` method. The error should be pretty clear

Comment: Your IDE should tell you whats wrong. This is not a question worth posting...

Comment: java naming conventions, please .. also mind the tags: this is entirely unrelated to javafx ..

Answer (score 1):

Add `add()` method in `TeamList` and your `list` is `null` by default and in constructor you are assigning instance which is `null` to itself

```
//Do below and remove constructor
private ArrayList<Team> teamList = new ArrayList<>();

//or

public class TeamList {
    private ArrayList<Team> teamList;

    public TeamList(){
        setTeamList(new ArrayList<Team>());
    }

    public ArrayList<Team> getTeamList() {
        return teamList;
    }

    public void add(Team team){
       teamList.add(team);
    }

    public void setTeamList(ArrayList<Team> teamList) {
        this.teamList = teamList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `teams` isn't an ArrayList, it's a `TeamList` object. Therefore, you can't use `.add()` because it is not of type ArrayList.

Make an `ArrayList<Team>` instead, and then use `.add(team)` with your new ArrayList.

Answer (score -5):

Use

```
ArrayList<TeamList> teams = new ArrayList<TeamList>();
```

to add the team to teams list

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the issue. Please try editing your answer to expand it and make it useful